# Period of non-harmonic Fourier sum

Tags: fft, nonuniform, nonharmonic

I am wondering if there is a formula for the period of the sum of $N$ cisoids of the form $e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N} i\, \omega_k}$ where the frequencies $\omega_k \in \left[-N/2,N/2\right]$, $k=0,\ldots,N-1$ and $\forall\, p,q,\, \omega_p \neq \omega_q$. This kernel arises, for instance, in the expression of the Non Uniform FFT (NUFFT).

Comment: Are the $\omega_k$ _integers_ between $−N/2$ and $+N/2$, or arbitrary real numbers in the interval $[−N/2,N/2]$? In the former case, look at the answers to [this question]( http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/8890/235). In the latter case, it is entirely possible that the sum is not a periodic function at all.

Comment: The $\omega_k$ are real numbers, however we can assume $\omega_k=\alpha\, n_k$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n_k \in \mathbb{N}$. I found some class notes explaining how in this case the fundamental has frequency $\alpha \gcd(n_0,\ldots,n_{N-1})$. I still would like to find a textbook or paper explaining this, so any pointer is very appreciated.